# When is a product of discrete spaces discrete?

Tags: general-topology

If $X$ is a discrete topological space ($\mathcal{T}=\mathcal{P}(x)$). Let I be a set.

I want to determine when the space $X^I$ with the product topology is discrete.

Now I know that $X^I$ defines all the applications $I \rightarrow X$ but I'm having trouble even knowing where to start in order to find the solution.

Answer (score 2):

Hints. (1) The case $|X|\le 1$ is trivial, so assume $|X|>1$. (2) If $I$ is infinite, any open set in $X^I$ is infinite. (3) What happens if $I$ is finite?